# Default webcam app

Tags: webcam

On a fresh 12.04 install what app does ubuntu use to take initial user profile pic?

I want to use the same app to run webcam tests.

Thanks

Comment: you may try `sudo apt-get install cheese`

Comment: I would suggest you to install Kamerka .Cheese sometimes gives poor picture quality as well as it stops working while recording a video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many applications are installed while Ubuntu is being installed but later removed to make the OS lighter and free from unwanted applications.

Some of them are:

- **gparted**- the application that you see when you partition your disk during installation
- **cheese**- the application that clicks your photo using your webcam during installation

To install cheese, go to your dash and type "software center", open the application and type "cheese" in the search bar on the top-right corner and click on "Install".

Comment: Ahh that makes sense. Good to know!